# DD ZFS Disks: The pool metadata is corrupt

Tags: data-recovery, zfs, truenas

I've was doing a full sync to another ZFS server when suddenly my main pool errors out and gets in a degraded state. Later that day, the PSU of the server died.

Perhaps it had something to do with the problem. To maximise my chances of recovery, I dd cloned every disk onto a brand new one. I then proceeded to clone the installation SSD to a new one as well. Then I built a new server and put all the cloned drives in.

However when I boot it up my pool was offline. Since it is a DD copy, and I still have the real ones, I proceeded to export the pool hoping I could import it again.

But it doesn't work (The pool metadata is corrupted).

The original drives + boot SSD still do work, but the pool is in degraded state. As I don't have backups (I was building a backup solution and doing the sync rip), I didn't want to risk doing ANYTHING to those disks and copied them beforehand.

But why doesn't it work? Everything is identical to the original drives, they're just DD clones.

It was a raidz2 pool of 8 4TB drives, here's the output of zpool import

```
root@truenas[~]# zpool import
   pool: Storage
     id: 6673942938673636213
  state: FAULTED
status: The pool metadata is corrupted.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
        The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
        the '-f' flag.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-72
 config:

        Storage                                         FAULTED  corrupted data
          raidz2-0                                      ONLINE
            gptid/7410ca04-fa3f-11eb-9fc5-448a5b9cb913  ONLINE
            gptid/74e17ef3-fa3f-11eb-9fc5-448a5b9cb913  ONLINE
            gptid/75ac2a30-fa3f-11eb-9fc5-448a5b9cb913  ONLINE
            gptid/759dd419-fa3f-11eb-9fc5-448a5b9cb913  ONLINE
            gptid/75941fd5-fa3f-11eb-9fc5-448a5b9cb913  ONLINE
            gptid/7588237a-fa3f-11eb-9fc5-448a5b9cb913  ONLINE
            gptid/75bcc114-fa3f-11eb-9fc5-448a5b9cb913  ONLINE
            gptid/75e2acc3-fa3f-11eb-9fc5-448a5b9cb913  ONLINE
```

The -f option also yielded no results.

I really don't want to touch the original disks anymore. The samba share was still online and I could access data in the degraded state. (in other words I really don't want to try srubbing the original disks).

Hope someone can help, thanks in advance!